# How to get the transport-key of ACOSJ Java Card?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have a number of blank ACOSJ Java Card from smartcardfocus:
https://www.smartcardfocus.us/shop/ilp/id~820/acosj-contact-only-java-card-40k-sim-cut/p/index.shtml

Currently every APDU command I send to the card will receive `0x6D00` back (instruction invalid). After some research, I find that I may need to obtain a transport-key and then pre-personalize the card before I can send any command.d

Any idea how I can get the transport-key? Is the key different for each card or the same for every ACOSJ card?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to ask the person you bought the cards for. Commonly there is a difference between generic cards and cards produced in volume for an important customer / reseller / OS manufacturer (a previous company I worked for bought millions of these *kind* of chips, so yeah, then you definitely get a non-generic one if you ask for it).

Comment: Demo cards usually use all keys set to the ordered bytes between 0x40 and 0x4F inclusive for Global Platform authentication by they way.